# Substituição dentro de virgulas no C#

Tags: c#

Bom dia pessoal.
Eu tenho a seguinte string:

```
string frutas = "f1,f2,f3,f4,...";
```

Basicamente eu quero que ele substitua o a palavra que está entre a 3° e 4° virgula por alguma coisa.
por exemplo: **maçã**

Ficando assim:

```
f1,f2,maçã,f4,..
```

Como posso fazer?

Comment: Tenta usar o split(), https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx faz as alterações que queres no vector e depois junta tudo outra vez

Comment: o que já tentou fazer? podes tentar com split (como citado acima), substring, regex.. mas precisa mostrar algo para podermos ajudar.

Comment: E o que difere da sua pergunta anterior?

Comment: Vou tentar o split.
Fui mais especifico nesta pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção...

```
var frutas = "f1,f2,f3,f4,...";

int posicaoSubstiuir = 3;
string valorSubstituir = "Maçã";

string[] arrFruta = frutas.Split(',');

if (arrFruta.Length >= posicaoSubstiuir)
    arrFruta[posicaoSubstiuir - 1] = valorSubstituir;

frutas = string.Join(",", arrFruta);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Funcionou perfeitamente!